# Converting paired list values to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of pairs like the following one:

```
[['A', 'B'],
 ['C', 'E'],
 ['F', 'D'],
 ['C', 'D'], 
 ['D', 'E'],
 ['G', 'E'],
 ['B', 'A'],
 ['H', 'G'],
 ['A', 'F'],
 ['E', 'A']]
```

I want to generate a dictionary with the first value in each pair as keys and the second one as value like the following:

```
{'A': ['B', 'F'], 
 'B': ['A'], 
 'C': ['E', 'D'], 
 'D': ['E'], 
 'E': ['A'], 
 'F': ['D', 'E'], 
 'G': ['E'], 
 'H': ['G']}
```

I used the following code, but didn't reached the desired outcome:

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

graph = {}
graph = graph.fromkeys(keys, [])

for row in pairs:
(graph[row[0]]).append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) will set all your values to the *same* list object! Use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead which will create a *new* list for each unknown key:

```
graph = {}

for row in pairs:
    graph.setdefault(row[0], []).append(row[1])
```

Alternatively, use a [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(list)        
for row in pairs:
    graph[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

Or, more elegantly:

```
for v1, v2 in in pairs:
    graph[v1].append(v2)
```